# adding multiple alarm in android using alarm manager

Tags: android

I am working on an android application. In this application I am trying to set multiple alarm with date-time taken from the user. I know this can be done using a broadcast receiver. Here is my code that I have tried:

```
private void setReminder(Calendar time){

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    alarmIntent.putExtra("name",teacherName);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, alarmIntent, 0);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC,time.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);

}
```

But the problem is it works for only one alarm. when I set multiple alarm the alarm responses for the last time that the user set with the result from the first alarm. what should I do to fire all the alarms correctly? A code with complete example with help me a lot. Thanks in advance

Comment: you have to set each alarm different ids. here PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), "ID", alarmIntent, 0);

Comment: okay but how can I update ID? if I close the app and open again. then how should I get the previous ID that was set before closing?

Comment: save ids in preference or db.

Answer (score 0):

add multiple alarm like:

```
    private void setReminder(Calendar time){

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent.putExtra("name",teacherName); 
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), getRandom(), alarmIntent, 0);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC,time.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);


    }
```

`getRandon()` function

```
 private int getRandom() {
        Random random = new Random();

        return random.nextInt(99999) + 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. 
Use for loop to make multiple alarms

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                ArrayList<PendingIntent> intentsArrayList = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

                for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
                {
                    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
                   // i the request code for every alarm with current position
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), i, alarmIntent, 0);                       
                    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC,
                            time.getTimeInMillis() + 60000 * i,
                            pendingIntent);
                    alarmIntent.putExtra("name",teacherName+i);
                    intentsArrayList.add(pendingIntent);
                }
```